# Как подключиться к PostgreSql в kotlin android?

Tags: android, postgresql, kotlin

я только недавно начал изучать Kotlin и хотел бы узнать, как мне использовать PostgreSql в моем приложении. Я написал такой код, но не работает:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
 fun getConnection(): Connection? {
     val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
     val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
     val username = "postgers"
     val password = "postgres"

     Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
     return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
 }
}
```

Я уже много сайтов перерыл и на иностранных ресурсах тоже посмотрел, нашел только подключение к Sqlite3, но мне это не подходит.

Это у меня написанно в MainActivity.kt:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     val databaseConnection = DatabaseConnection()
     val connection = databaseConnection.getConnection()

     val statement = connection?.createStatement()
     val resultSet = statement?.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users")

     while (resultSet?.next() == true) {
         val id = resultSet.getInt("id")
         val name = resultSet.getString("name")
         Log.d("My", "id - $id \t name - $name")
     }
     resultSet?.close()
     statement?.close()
 }
```

Ошибка при запуске кода:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2023-08-09 19:33:56.765 11458-11458/com.karabok.spescmaster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.karabok.spescmaster, PID: 11458
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.karabok.spescmaster/com.karabok.spescmaster.MainActivity}: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
     at com.karabok.spescmaster.Database.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.kt:19)
     at com.karabok.spescmaster.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:619)
     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) 
     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) 
     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) 
     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) 
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218) 
     at com.karabok.spescmaster.Database.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.kt:19) 
     at com.karabok.spescmaster.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
2023-08-09 19:33:56.805 11458-11458/com.karabok.spescmaster I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11458 SIG: 9
```

Прошу вас дайте мне ответ с объяснениями или ссылку на ресурс, где подробно описано, как это сделать.

Comment: Разрешение на интернет в манифесте есть `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`?

Comment: @woesss я попробовал поставить это разрешение, но у меня теперь другая ошибка, org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Я сейчас смотрю ее способы решения, а еще у меня появились мысли о том, что у Postgres не получается подключиться (или приложение на телефоне не может этого сделать), по причине того, что я использую localhost и к бд может быть подключение только в рамках компьютера

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, а еще лучше в поиск. Песня про localhost в Андроиде стара как сам Андроид.

Comment: Я сейчас запустил postgres в termux на моем телефоне похоже, что я был прав, сейчас эта ошибка пропала и теперь мне нужно подключиться бд. сейчас ошибка FATAL EXCEPTION: main - это общее описание ошибки (то что в начала лога), а это конкретно сама проблема Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: